# Magento Multi Store Redirect loop

Tags: apache, magento, ssl, vhosts, opensuse

I'm using Magento 1.6.2.0.,  Apache, Fast CGI, OpenSUSE

I have set up Multi Store successfully by redirecting a different domain using vhost.conf and vhost_ssl.conf, and by altering the .htaccess in the 'root' domain. I need to do it this way because I need 2 separate IP addresses and 2 SSL certs. The redirect works and I have been able to skin the new domain to my liking.

.htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf Host .*domain.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain_code
SetEnvIf Host .*domain.* SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

vhost_ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_suexec.c>
    SuexecUserGroup "user" "xxxx"
</IfModule>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/dev.domain.co.uk"

<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domain.co.uk/dev.domain.co.uk>
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    <Files ~ (\.php)>
        SetHandler fcgid-script
        FCGIWrapper /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper .php
        Options +ExecCGI
        allow from all
    </Files>
</IfModule>
SSLRequireSSL
Options -Includes -ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

My concern is that whenever I try to navigate to an https:// page I get a redirect loop in the browser.

I have no SSL cert set up for this domain, but to my mind this should not create this error, but rather a 'no cert' error (if anything).

I was hoping that someone might be able to point out a solution that they have had in the past.

Thanks for any time that anyone spends on this.

Comment: have you checked your `core_config_data` table and cleared Magento's cache?

Comment: No, what do you think that I ought to be looking for? The URLs fot http and https are all good.

Comment: try viewing the redirects using `curl -L -D /dev/stderr https://etc...`

Comment: Turns out that the SSL cert was the issue. Although I never got to the bottom of what was causing the redirect once the SSL was configured correctly, then everything seemed to be fine from then.